# Assigning nulls' in the Gson custom serialization for Double fields

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I am trying to serialize the following class to Json using Gson custom serialization.

```
public class Product{
   public String prodId;
   public Double prodPrice;
}
```

I want to check if the Double property(prodPrice) has a value of "-1.0" and assign null value to the field if it is "-1.0". I have the written the following Gson custom serializer for doing it.

```
public class GsonUtil {

public static String getJSONString(Object input) throws Exception {
    if (input == null) {
        throw new Exception("JSON Conversion failed. Input string is null");
    }

    try {

        JsonSerializer<Double> dser = getDoubleSerializer();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Double.class, dser)
                .create();

        String jsonStr = gson.toJson(input);

        if (jsonStr == null) {
            throw new Exception("Json String is null");
        }
        return jsonStr;

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return null;
}

private static JsonSerializer<Double> getDoubleSerializer() {
    JsonSerializer<Double> ser = new JsonSerializer<Double>() {


        public JsonElement serialize(Double dval, Type arg1,
                JsonSerializationContext arg2) {

            if(!(dval.equals(-1.0))){
                return new JsonPrimitive(dval);
            }
            else{
                Double retVal = null;
                return new JsonPrimitive(retVal);
            }

        }
    };
    return ser;
}

}
```

When I do this the custom serializer is not working and when I tried to assign some other value apart from null, the same custom serialization is working fine.

Please let me know if I am doing some thing wrong and let me know if it can be achieved using any other way.
Thank you.

Comment: What happens when it determines the value is `-1` and returns a `JsonPrimitive` with an assigned `null` value?  Is the field skipped?

Comment: I am not getting any error and at the same time I am unable to see any response. All I am getting is a blank response.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a single `Gson` instance not creating another ones every time you might need such deserialization. Gson supports special type adapters that can be bound to a particular object field and annotated with `@JsonAdapter`. Note that it wouldn't affect another objects of the same type unless they are annotated with this annotation, so the original Gson configuration is preserved.

So you `Product.java` can have the annotation for `prodPrice` field:

```java
final class Product {

    @SerializedName("prodId")
    String id;

    @JsonAdapter(SpecialDoubleTypeAdapter.class)
    @SerializedName("prodPrice")
    Double price;

}
```

Now just create a special type adapter that would match your requirements:

```java
final class SpecialDoubleTypeAdapter
        extends TypeAdapter<Double> {

    private static final TypeAdapter<Double> specialDoubleTypeAdapter = new SpecialDoubleTypeAdapter();

    // Gson can instantiate it itself even with a private constructor
    private SpecialDoubleTypeAdapter() {
    }

    // In case if it's necessary to instantiate it manually
    static TypeAdapter<Double> getSpecialDoubleTypeAdapter() {
        return specialDoubleTypeAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final Double value)
            throws IOException {
        // write the value as null if no value provided or it's considered "illegal" (however it's a good place to review and the right-hand expression)
        if ( value != null || value < 0 ) {
            out.value(value);
        } else {
            out.nullValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Double read(final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        final JsonToken token = in.peek();
        switch ( token ) {
        case NULL:
            // read the null token, this is mandatory
            in.nextNull();
            return null;
        case NUMBER:
            // read the number token as double
            final double d = in.nextDouble();
            // assuming the negative price should be null, not just -1.0
            return d >= 0 ? d : null;
        // an opinion-based case group: you can use default
        // but in my opinion explicit mapping is explicit
        case BEGIN_ARRAY:
        case END_ARRAY:
        case BEGIN_OBJECT:
        case END_OBJECT:
        case NAME:
        case STRING:
        case BOOLEAN:
        case END_DOCUMENT:
            throw new MalformedJsonException("Unexpected token: " + token);
        // so this would never happen unless Gson adds a new token some day...
        default:
            throw new AssertionError("must never happen");
        }
    }

}
```

And just make a little test:

```java
public static void main(final String... args) {
    final Gson gson = new Gson();
    test(gson, "{\"prodId\":\"good\",\"prodPrice\":100}");
    test(gson, "{\"prodId\":\"bad\",\"prodPrice\":-1}");
}

private static void test(final Gson gson, final String json) {
    final Product product = gson.fromJson(json, Product.class);
    out.print("Product ");
    out.print(product.id);
    out.print(", price ");
    out.println(product.price);
}
```

The demo above will produce:

> Product good, price 100.0
>   Product bad, price null

### Edit 1

Your serializer has some design issues. The major one is that your code swallows an exception if it happens, and I'm sorry I've missed it when I saw `Double retVal = null; return new JsonPrimitive(retVal);`. Please never do like that -- or your code will ever keep silence for serious issues. Next thing, you can rethrow the exception and this is what it gets:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive.isPrimitiveOrString(JsonPrimitive.java:278)
    at com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive.setValue(JsonPrimitive.java:101)
    at com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive.<init>(JsonPrimitive.java:56)
    at q42278197.m2.Q42278197$1.serialize(Q42278197.java:77)
    at q42278197.m2.Q42278197$1.serialize(Q42278197.java:71)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter.write(TreeTypeAdapter.java:81)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:669)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:648)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:603)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:583)
    at q42278197.m2.Q42278197.getJSONString(Q42278197.java:58)
    ... 7 more
```

The root cause is: `Class<?> classOfPrimitive = target.getClass();` in Gson. Gson has a special JSON `null` element: the `JsonNull` singleton with the only instance `INSTANCE`. So your `JsonSerializer` might return it for not existing value: `return JsonNull.INSTANCE;`

Here is a redesigned implementation:

```java
private static String toJsonBySpecialDoubles(final Object input)
        throws NullPointerException {
    if ( input == null ) {
        throw new NullPointerException("input");
    }
    return specialDoubleGson.toJson(input);
}

private static final Gson specialDoubleGson = new GsonBuilder()
        .serializeNulls()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Double.class, getSpecialDoubleSerializer())
        .create();

private static JsonSerializer<Double> getSpecialDoubleSerializer() {
    return (value, type, context) -> !value.equals(-1.0) ? new JsonPrimitive(value) : JsonNull.INSTANCE;
}
```

Note that Java 8 lambda is used, but you can easily convert it to an anonymous class. Also note that you can have a single Gson instance. And that is probably all you need, because Gson can handle nulls itself, and so forth.

Comment: ...Thank for the response. But I have some 100 Double properties which have to be serialized in the same fashion and I am trying to explore an option where I can skip the work of adding annotation on the each and every Double field.

Comment: @SubbaramiReddyMalkireddy Well, you didn't mention it in your question. Also, however it might be a subject to debate, making the field annotated with annotation makes what happens to that field explicit -- especially when you transform the incoming data with data loss.

Comment: @SubbaramiReddyMalkireddy Also note that for the "process all doubles implicitly" strategy you can get two caveats: 1) this would work totally for all `Double` fields, even for those that are not meant to be processed like that; 2) Gson can traverse a given object recursively, so you could affect even fields that are referenced via another objects.

Comment: ..Thank you for the response. I found it helpful and started implementing it. But I am not getting the expected response. I could notice that the overridden "read" method is never being invoked while the write method is being invoked.

Comment: @SubbaramiReddyMalkireddy It must work in both directions. How are you using Gson to read the JSON?

Comment: @ Lyubomyr Shaydariv---Thank you...I got it...I have never converted Json to a POJO (That is the reason why 'read' method is not invoked). When ever I have serialized a POJO with few Double fields its works absolutely fine but whenever I used it on my POJO where there are around 200 Double values the custom serialization is getting failed and returning a blank response. I am not sure if this can be fixed. Thanks in advace.

Comment: @SubbaramiReddyMalkireddy Could you post how you're actually reading it? Your serializer looks good at the first glance, and probably you're missing something else? Maybe some response just gets swallowed or whatever else, because it sounds like your POJO just has a non-trivial case that does not occur in your POJO with fewer fields. + A sidenote: maybe you need to reconsider your data model and mapping? Frankly speaking, a POJO having about 200 fields sounds extremely not trivial.

Comment: @ Lyubomyr Shaydariv--- "Failing to convert a value or converting too many values may cause the application to crash". I found the above statement in the following link "https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html".

Comment: @SubbaramiReddyMalkireddy It would be nice if there also the reason could be stated... Anyway, I created my own deserializer similar to your approach. Note that it I can handle many fields (I generated about 300 fields), and my serializer is able to convert it. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @ Lyubomyr Shaydariv....Thank you for the update and I will try to debug my application and see if something else is causing it to break.

Comment: @ Lyubomyr Shaydariv....Thank a lot...The update you gave worked for me.